# An issue of iOS app update

Tags: ios

Can I add a "check update" button in the application Settings interface and then Submit to the apple store. Will it be rejected? If I can't add button to check updates, is there another way to detect  whether there is a new application update?

Comment: You will need a push server for this, just simply send a push message to all user when you have your app updated to mention they to update to newest version

Comment: The iOS App Store app already shows a badge when apps are available for upgrading. Many users even set up their devices to update apps automatically. Is there a point to doing it this way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes. You can add to check update available or not. And also you can know whether update is available or not. First you need to get the current app version number from info.plist file. Later you have to fetch version number from apple itunes. Now compare both updates and if appstore version is greater than current version, show a popup saying new update is available. This whole thing you can do it from AppDelegate when user every time launches app or from wherever based on your requirement.

Here is how to fetch version numbers:

**Swift Version**

```
  func appUpdateAvailable(storeInfoURL: String) -> Bool
    {
        var upgradeAvailable = false

        // Get the main bundle of the app so that we can determine the app's version number
        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        if let infoDictionary = bundle.infoDictionary {
            // The URL for this app on the iTunes store uses the Apple ID for the  This never changes, so it is a constant
            let urlOnAppStore = NSURL(string: storeInfoURL)
            if let dataInJSON = NSData(contentsOfURL: urlOnAppStore!) {
                // Try to deserialize the JSON that we got
                if let lookupResults = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataInJSON, options: NSJSONReadingOptions()) {
                    // Determine how many results we got. There should be exactly one, but will be zero if the URL was wrong
                    if let resultCount = lookupResults["resultCount"] as? Int {
                        if resultCount == 1 {
                            // Get the version number of the version in the App Store
                            if let appStoreVersion = lookupResults["results"]!![0]["version"] as? String {
                                // Get the version number of the current version
                                if let currentVersion = infoDictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
                                    // Check if they are the same. If not, an upgrade is available.
                                    if appStoreVersion != currentVersion {
                                        upgradeAvailable = true                      
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return upgradeAvailable
    }
```

**Objective-C**

```
 -(BOOL) needsUpdate{
    NSDictionary* infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString* appID = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=%@", appID]];
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary* lookup = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    if ([lookup[@"resultCount"] integerValue] == 1){
        NSString* appStoreVersion = lookup[@"results"][0][@"version"];
        NSString* currentVersion = infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
        if (![appStoreVersion isEqualToString:currentVersion]){
            NSLog(@"Need to update [%@ != %@]", appStoreVersion, currentVersion);
            return YES;
            }
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

Comment: Very glad to receive your answer, your answer gave me a big help, thank you!